# Microsoft Project unable to establish a connection with Project Server 2016

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2016

I just built a Project Server 2016 and have connection troubles. Since this is a proof of concept, I did not use TLS. The URL is just http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/sites/PWA I'm using the Project Permissions Mode.

I am testing with an unactivated copy of Project Professional 2013

[image: MS Project version number]

I set the version in PWA Settings
[image: Version Setting]

My client computer is not in the same domain as my Project Server. I choose the domain\user name when starting MS Project:
[image: Login dialog]

Project does not prompt for a password. It immediately gives an error:
[image: Error message unable to establish connection]

So next time, I choose work offline. Project opens and I check the Info page:
[image: Info: not connected]

I click Connect to Server and it does. Still no password prompt.
[image: Info: connected]

However, I cannot open a project from the Project Server.

[image: Unable to display projects]

Meanwhile, I have no problems on PWA making, editing, saving, publishing, checking in, etc. I made a new project and set the permissions correctly.
[image: Group permissions]

When I try to open it in Project by clicking the icon on the web page,

[image: web page icon]

I get the same error.

[image: Same error message]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate it when I discover my own dumb mistake an hour after posting a question.
Apparently, you must only use alphanumeric characters when you Add a Project Web Account in MS Project.

1. In the Info -> Manage Accounts -> Project Web Accounts dialog box, I deleted my Project Web accounts except "Computer"
2. I closed and restarted MS Project Professional
3. In the Info -> Manage Accounts -> Project Web Accounts dialog box, I added a new account but I only used letters in the Name field
4. I closed and restarted MS Project Professional
5. Logged into the new Project Web Account

Everything works now.

Apologies for wasting your time. Thanks for looking.